# Primefaces Reflow Table - Empty message begins after the first column header text

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, responsive-design, datatables

I´m trying to make my page resposive using the primefaces. But I have some trouble with tables, specially when the tables are empty.

This is my table code:

```
   <p:dataTable id="tabela" 
                                 var="minLote" 
                                 value="#{associarLoteBean.minLotes}" 
                                 rowKey="#{minLote.idLote}"
                                 selectionMode="single" 
                                 selection="#{associarLoteBean.minLoteSelecionado}" 
                                 paginator="true"
                                 reflow="true"
                                 emptyMessage="#{txt.no_herds_on_the_table}">

                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{associarLoteBean.onRowSelectDataTable}" />

                        <p:column headerText="#{txt.herd}"
                            filterBy="#{minLote.descricao}" filterStyle="display:none">
                            <h:outputText value="#{minLote.lote}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{txt.property}" 
                            filterBy="#{minLote.propriedade}" filterStyle="display:none">
                            <h:outputText value="#{minLote.propriedade}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{txt.current_pasture}"
                            filterBy="#{minLote.pasto}" filterStyle="display:none">
                            <h:outputText value="#{minLote.pasto}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="#{txt.animals_in_herd}"
                            filterBy="#{minLote.animais}" filterStyle="display:none">
                            <h:outputText value="#{minLote.animais}" />
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
```

When the table are empty and I decrease the size of the browser screen, the empty message is showed after the first column header text. The point is that when the screen is in normal size, that header text doesn't  appear before the empty message.

Someone has a idea to solve this?

Comment: Known issue in PrimeFaces 0.9.6

Comment: Searching by the primefaces issues, I found it -> https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1226

Comment: I joked to get you to tell your version. But I indeed knew it was reported. Good you found it. But stating your version helps always.

Comment: Primafaces 5.3 from community download. I saw that error was corrected, but only in the repository and not in the last .jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in the PrimeFaces 5.3.9 Elite release and in the upcoming 6.0 of which you can build a snapshot release in from the source in github